# Why am I getting null?

Tags: java, methods, null

So I have separate classes and I'm learning how to incorporate them into each other with methods. Looking for an explanation on why I'm getting null for some methods, I've been stuck on this for hours.

Main "Bagel" class:

```
  public class Bagels {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Player first = new Player();
    Engine second = new Engine();

    System.out.println("Welcome!");

    second.getNumDigits();
    first.getName();

    System.out.println("Starting game #" +first.gamesCompleted );
    System.out.println("" );


    first.askForGuess();

    second.setGuessConvert(first);

    second.convertNumtoDigitArray(second.guessConvert);

    second.generateNewSecret();


    System.out.println("" + second.userGuessArray.length); //NULL error when run
    System.out.println("" + second.secretNumber.length); //NULL error when run

    Validator.validateGuess(second.secretNumber, second.userGuessArray, second.numDigits);
```

Engine class:

```
    import java.util.Random;
   import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Engine {

public int numDigits, numDigitsSet;
public int i;
public int[] secretNumber, userGuessArray;
public Random randomNumberGenerator;
public String guessConvert;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void setNumDigits()
{

    numDigitsSet = numDigits;

}

public void setGuessConvert(Player player)
{
    guessConvert = player.userGuess;
}

public int getNumDigits()
{
    System.out.print("Enter the number of digits to use: ");
    return numDigits = sc.nextInt();

}

public void generateNewSecret() //NULL
{
Random rand = new Random();{
for (int i=0; i<numDigitsSet; i++)
{
    secretNumber[i]= rand.nextInt(10);

        }
    }
}

public int[] getSecretNumber()
{
     for (int j=0; j<secretNumber.length; j++) //NULL
     {
         System.out.println("" + secretNumber[j]);
     }
    return secretNumber;
}

public void convertNumtoDigitArray(String guessConvert) //NULL
{
    String[] userGuessSplit = guessConvert.split(",");
    int[] userGuessArray = new int[userGuessSplit.length];
    for (int j=0; j<userGuessSplit.length; j++)
    {
        userGuessArray[j] = Integer.parseInt(userGuessSplit[j]);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: "You're getting null for some methods" How about showing which methods are returning `null`?

Comment: In the code you have shown, nothing ever sets `userGuessArray` or `secretNumber` - thus they default to null.

Comment: @Kon Sorry sir, added //null on the methods

Comment: @John3136 But I thought I set them in the methods? or Do I need to set them elsewhere

Comment: @Nadal You try to use them like `secretNumber[i]` but you haven't actually set the array with `secretNumber = new int[someSize];` so the actual arrays are null. When you try to dereference, it fails. I'd suggest you close this question since it doesn't really meet the criteria of being useful to others.

Comment: Crystal...Ball... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In generateNewSecret function of Engine class, you have to init secretNumber before using

```
    public void generateNewSecret()
    {
    Random rand = new Random();{
secretNumber =  new int[numDigitsSet];
    for (int i=0; i<numDigitsSet; i++)
    {
        secretNumber[i]= rand.nextInt(10);

            }
        }
    }
```

In convertNumtoDigitArray function, I think you should check guessConvert, may be there is not commas in it.

```
public void convertNumtoDigitArray(String guessConvert)
{
    String[] userGuessSplit = guessConvert.split(",");
    int[] userGuessArray = new int[userGuessSplit.length];
    for (int j=0; j<userGuessSplit.length; j++)
    {
        userGuessArray[j] = Integer.parseInt(userGuessSplit[j]);
    }
}
```